# how to run mobile app using ionic in real device

Tags: ionic3

I want to run app with ionic view app in my real device 
I tried in the first time

```
ionic link
```

after

```
ionic upload
```

when i run the last command i get this error

[image: error]

can anyone help me please ?
and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can run your Ionic project on a real device with the following command, for example for an Android device:

```
ionic cordova run android --device
```

Your Android device must be connected to your computer and you will have to allow debugging on your Android device.

[`ionic link`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/link/) is actually used to connect your local app to Ionic'online service.

To check that your device is recognized and Ionic will be able to transfer the apk, use the following command

```
adb devices
```

You should see your Android device listed.

Comment: i use it but i didn't see execution on my device

Comment: D:\Master m1 big data\5Developpement mobile\ionicproject\ioniclynda\appvid39_musica>ionic cordova ru
n --android

Comment: Sorry, I updated the command, it is: `ionic cordova run android --device`

Comment: the end of the command is this   
[OK] Your app has been deployed.
     Did you know you can live-reload changes from your app with --livereload?


D:\Master m1 big data\5Developpement mobile\ionicproject\ioniclynda\appvid39_musica>

Answer (score 0):

1. turn on the developer option on your mobile.
2. Check your device is recognized - `adb devices`
3. Go your ionic application folder and run `npm i -g cordova`
4. `ionic cordova run android --prod`